# detect an error on html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to detect when there is an error on playing a video in html5.

To be more specific, My use case is when one is trying to play an HLS video in MAC (so "canPlayType" is at least "maybe") - yet for some reason the video does not play.

I have tried listening to 'error' event on the video tag. Doesn't work. In fact, the 'error' event is not even firing if I use an invalid url source!
(See a demo here: http://mockup.on.aol.com/yogev/hls.html)

Could anyone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen the console of your browser.Is it showing some errors??

Comment: Yes. I have made it respond with 404 when using an invalid url.
I have made it respond with 403 using a url from Akamai with an invalid token.

Nothing seems to trigger the 'error' event...

If you are talking about an error in the code - please look at the demo I have posted. There is NOTHING there but a video tag...

Answer (score 3):

You should add error event listener before you set the source of the video.
So, if you add this after your error listener, you will get error callback:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].src='https://someFalseurl.mp4';
```

Your current demo page is creating error listener after the error has already passed.

Comment: Thanks, but now it's adding the event listeners before I throw in the src - and still nothing gets fired...
I have also added some more events like 'abort', 'suspend', etc and still NOTHING fires!

Comment: Error should be fired when you set invalid source. Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26tzkvy5/ it should show error alert message.